# How can I add rules to a branch in git cmd?

Tags: git, cmd

I want to set couple of rules to my master branch.
One of the rules is to have mandatory code review when pull request.
I know that I can do this in GIT HUB app but can I set this in git in the cmd?
[GitHub branch rules settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmTum.png)

Comment: Remember that git and github are not the same thing. In git, branches don't have rules (it kinda doesn't make sense). May you add examples? What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but can I set this in git in the cmd?

No, because it has nothing at all to do with Git. It is a GitHub feature. Branch rules, and pull requests, do not exist in Git at all (though Git does have commit hooks you can configure locally).

Do not confuse Git and GitHub. Git is a command line tool. GitHub is a web site, and has nothing to do with Git except the name. Behind the scenes, GitHub is running Git as a server, but there's nothing special about that. Everything else about GitHub *is* special and is not Git.

You might be able to do what you're trying to do using the `gh` command line tool.

https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_workflow

But again, that's GitHub, not Git.